# Heroku - assets loading partially

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have just deployed my app to heroku and I found a weird behavior. Every single image of my website was precompiled (as they are all displaying properly), except two of them.

I am using Rails 5.0.0.1 and I did not know about heroku precompilation until now.

What might be the cause of this behavior?
Can I run this compliation directly on heroku or do I have to add some lines of code to make it work?

Comment: what are the urls of those images? if you properly use the `image_tag` or other asset helpers, there should not be a problem.

Comment: I do use image_tag. The urls look like other image urls that I do not have problem with. That is why this is so weird.